# Promise .then() Not Waiting For Resolve() Of the Previous Promise In A Promise Chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

I am very new to the concept of Promises but I read that this is an efficient way of making functions execute one after another by doing something called Promise chaining.

The //RUN ON CLCK: CREATE TABLES code below basically makes two AJAX calls, "Create Database Tables" and "Check Database Tables", so that when I press a button on the webpage, Database Tables will be created on the backend, and then their existence will be checked.

But it doesn't run as intended. In many cases, as obseved from the console log, the second function runs (or) finishes first. In any case, that shouldn't happen in a chain.

It looks like the 2nd function is not waiting for a resolve from the 1st function.

Please note that my functions have arguments so I can't avoid calling them without parentheses inside the then() as some other articles recommend.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /*PAGE VARS*/
    var mainAdmStgChkTblSrvltMsg_elm = document.getElementById('mainAdmStgChkTblSrvltMsg');
    var mainAdmStgCrDelTblSrvltMsg_elm = document.getElementById('mainAdmStgCrDelTblSrvltMsg');
    var mainAdmStgCrTblBtn_elm = document.getElementById('mainAdmStgCrTblBtn');

    /*FN DEF: CHECK TABLES*/
    var chkTbl = function(tblNm) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '../../../../../../app/TblSrvlt',
                data: {
                    getType: 'chkTbl',
                    tblNm: tblNm
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var srvltMsg = data.srvltMsg;
                    var srvltSuccess = data.srvltSuccess;
                    mainAdmStgChkTblSrvltMsg_elm.textContent = srvltMsg;
                    if (srvltSuccess === true) {
                        mainAdmStgChkTblSrvltMsg_elm.setAttribute('class', 'text-success');
                    } else {
                        mainAdmStgChkTblSrvltMsg_elm.setAttribute('class', 'text-danger');
                    }
                    /*RETURN RESOLVE FOR PROMISE CHAIN*/
                    console.log("chkTbl");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    };

    /*FN DEF: CREATE TABLES*/
    var crTbl = function(tblNm) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../../../../../app/TblSrvlt',
                data: {
                    postType: 'crTbl',
                    tblNm: tblNm
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var srvltMsg = data.srvltMsg;
                    var srvltSuccess = data.srvltSuccess;
                    mainAdmStgCrDelTblSrvltMsg_elm.textContent = srvltMsg;
                    if (srvltSuccess === true) {
                        mainAdmStgCrDelTblSrvltMsg_elm.setAttribute('class', 'text-success');
                    } else {
                        mainAdmStgCrDelTblSrvltMsg_elm.setAttribute('class', 'text-danger');
                    }
                    /*RETURN RESOLVE FOR PROMISE CHAIN*/
                    console.log("crTbl");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    };

    /*RUN ON CLCK: CREATE TABLES*/
    $(document).on('click', '#' + mainAdmStgCrTblBtn_elm.id, function() {
        Promise.resolve()
            .then(crTbl("chairs"))
            .then(chkTbl("chairs"))
            .catch();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're calling both when you create the promise chain, and passing the *results* as the callbacks.

Comment: How about

 $(document).on('click', '#' + mainAdmStgCrTblBtn_elm.id,  
   crTbl("chairs").then(chkTbl("chairs")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a function reference to `.then()` so it can call your function LATER.  Instead, you are calling the functions immediately and passing their return value to `.then()` which is why they are getting called immediately and not waiting for the prior promise to resolve.

Change this:

```
/*RUN ON CLCK: CREATE TABLES*/
$(document).on('click', '#' + mainAdmStgCrTblBtn_elm.id, function() {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(crTbl("chairs"))
        .then(chkTbl("chairs"))
        .catch();
});
```

to this:

```
/*RUN ON CLCK: CREATE TABLES*/
$(document).on('click', '#' + mainAdmStgCrTblBtn_elm.id, function() {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(function() {return crTbl("chairs")})
        .then(function() {return chkTbl("chairs")})
        .catch(function(err) { console.log(err)});
});
```

And, you don't actually need the `Promise.resolve()` at the start of the chain:

```
/*RUN ON CLCK: CREATE TABLES*/
$(document).on('click', '#' + mainAdmStgCrTblBtn_elm.id, function() {
     crTbl("chairs")
        .then(function() {return chkTbl("chairs")})
        .catch(function(err) { console.log(err)});
});
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, it didn't work. I even tried removing arguments but it seems to chain properly only sometimes.

Comment: @KhenHermoso - There are all sorts of other programming problems with your `chkTbl()` and `crTbl()` functions.  For starters, they never reject their promise if the ajax call has an error (they essentially have NO error handling of any kind).  They are also an example of a promise anti-pattern because `$.ajax()` already returns a promise so you don't need to construct a new promise - you can just use and return the one that `$.ajax()` already makes.  And, your lack of error handling is one of the gotchas with this anti-pattern.

Comment: I understand about those other problems but really right now I'm just trying to learn to solve the promise().then() issue. Also it's true that ajax returns a promise. But i'm trying to look at the chkTbl() and crTbl() as a general function that returns a promise, not an ajax call. So when I figure it out, I'll be able to write a promise chain for any general function that returns a promise. I also deliberately removed the reject() of these functions because according to the doc, they'll just go to the the first .then() with a reject of the chain or the catch(), so it seems unneeded for this.

Comment: Ok it tried your solution again and now it works. I have no idea why it didn't work the first time. Thank you very much!. Even if I put a delay on the servlet, it definitely waits for the resolve.